# Best way to count 1's of a binary number

Tags: java, binary, bit-shift

Doing a question on codility and was Asked to take two numbers and get the product. Then get the binary repesentation of that number and count the number of one's that are in the binary number. 
My code is

```
    return method(int a, int b)
    {
    int count=0;
    int num;
    num = a* b;
    while(num>0)
    {
       if(num %2 ==1)
       {
           count++;
       }
     num = num >> 1;
    }
  return count;
  }
```

Yet it only gives 50% correctness. Can anyone explain this. Is there something i missed that i should be aware off.

Comment: `a*b` could be greater than 32 bits, at least use `long num = (long)a*b;`

Comment: a or b could be negative, use `>>>` instead of `>>`

Comment: don't use `%` use `&1` to test parity

Comment: @Lashane Don't post comments, post an answer!

Comment: I am curious what 50% correctness means

Comment: 50% means the answer is half right. I know i never seen it before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the modulo operator won't correctly count the bits in a negative number.  Use "num & 1" instead.  Also, make sure you're using unsigned right shifts or a negative number may produce an infinite loop.

And as Lashane said, use a 64 bit product if possible.